# edit Jtable properties

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I am new in java and I have a task to do
I have a swing JTable , and I want to disable rows editing and keep the selection available .
I am using this code

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    return false;
            }
```

I did not initialize the table dynamically ,but by drag and drop from swing.
my question is how to add this code to my table, do I have to change the swing to another type?

Comment: You should create your own `TableModel` and use this method in that... See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: is there a way to do the task to an existing jTable?

Answer (score 0):

If you dragged and dropped the JTable from an editor ( for example if you are using NetBeans or Eclipse which have a designer included in) you just have to select JTable item and set the Editable proprety to disabled:

[image]

anyway as Oracle Javadoc suggest at this link: [JavaDoc_JTable_setCellSelection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setCellSelectionEnabled(boolean))

you could also set to false with method:

```
YourJTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I suggest you to create a TableModel and create your table starting by it. This will give you more options about column/row creation, column/row modify, datas import/export from any source, this is not included by default in a java.swing.JTable